# How to implement a smart search box to query data from database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

- I want to implement the **search box** that will :

  **query** all the inventory from my **inventories** table in my **database**.
- I **only** want to display the search input box, and **NOT** listing any of my item as a start.
- I came across a nice plug-in call [**DataTable**](http://www.datatables.net/). I used it. I like it.
- I want to stick with this plug-in, and just tweak this a little bit to fit my need.

Here is what I have :

[image]

Here is what I want to have :

I found this one at  [Here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/expanding-search-button-in-css)

How do I hide any data as a start ?

[image]

Comment: DataTables is a plugin for tabular data, it can be used to perform a server-side search on your database (so the table could be initially empty or even hidden but then you'd need to link it to a search field so that the search value is copied to the DataTables filter but that might not be what you actually want to do) but I think your question is too broad.

Comment: I liked your suggestion, can you provide more details on how to `link it to a search field` as you said. As a matter of fact, this is exactly what I want to do. I hope you don't mind answer it.

Comment: well if you are using jQuery you could copy the search field value to the DataTables filter value and trigger the search. There might be a better way than that but the best thing to do is read the DataTables documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to get the data from the server side in the form of a JSON object. once   you get the data you can use this simple to populate the searched data in list   format. You have complete control on which information you want to show.

  Refer to this [link][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_2022/56wjeu7y/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

First , hide the default search box :

```
.dataTables_filter {
   display: none;
}
```

Second, create your own searchbox somewhere in the HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="searchbox">
```

Third, script to search / filter when typing in the search box

```
$("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
   dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
});
```

working demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/TbrtF/